# Getting LastLogon and LastLogonTimeStamp from ALL Domain Controllers into 1 output CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So far I have this:

```
Get-ADDomainController -filter * | 
% {Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -server $_.name -Properties         Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,LastLogon,Manager,Title,Department,Organization,Enabled -SearchBase "DC=webcoindustries,DC=com" | 
? {$_.EmployeeID -notlike "EXCLUDE" } | 
Select Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,@{N='Last‌​Logon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}},Manager,Title,Department,Organizatio‌​n,Enabled | 
Export-Csv "C:\scripts\AD_Export_Test\AD_Export_$($_.name).csv"}
```

This only pulls LastLogon into multiple CSV files (1 for each Domain Controller). However, what I would like to be done is for the script to also pull LastLogonTimeStamp, compare the two, and use the whichever one is most recent. I also would like to have the full end result only be in one final CSV file. Is this possible all in one script?

Comment: If you are pulling the LastLogon from all domain controllers then there's no point to pulling the LastLogonTimestamp because that is only updated if the LastLogon is more than 7-11 days old (I think that's the range, it's like 6+(random 1-5) days). Also, do you want all of the individual CSVs left at the end or replace them with this?

Comment: Why do you need to fetch a metric ton of attributes when all you want is the last logon? Also, `LastLogonTimestamp` is a [consolidated attribute](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx). It can never be more recent than the most recent `lastLogon` timestamp.

Comment: I must have misunderstood LastLogonTimeStamp then, from the sounds of it I don't need it, awesome. Thanks for the clarification on that. @TheMadTechnician I would rather just replace the individual CSVs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple `Group`, followed by `Sort`, and `Select -First 1` in a `ForEach` loop would solve this problem.

```psh
Get-ADDomainController -filter * | 
% {Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True' -and EmployeeID -notlike 'EXCLUDE'" -server $_.name -Properties         Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,LastLogon,Manager,Title,Department,Organization,Enabled -SearchBase "DC=webcoindustries,DC=com" | 
Select Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,@{N='Last‌​Logon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}},Manager,Title,Department,Organizatio‌​n,Enabled}|
Group samaccountname |
ForEach{$_.Group | Sort LastLogon -Descending | Select -First 1} |
Export-Csv "C:\scripts\AD_Export_Test\AD_Export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I also moved your `EmployeeID -notlike "EXCLUDE"` filter from the `Where` statement into your `Get-ADUser` filter, and got rid of the `Where` statement

Comment: This didn't quite work. It output to 1 file; however, a majority of the users were given the LastLogon of '12/31/1600 6:00:00 PM'. Before when I ran the code those same users had different Date and Times, and I know for a fact the users have logged on before. Any reason why I may be getting this output?

Comment: No reason that I can think of unless one or more of your DC's timed out or something and didn't send back a list of users, and that's the DC the user connected to.

Comment: I got it to work, for some reason there were multiple different 'LastLogon' instances that looked the same, but once I retyped it, it seemed to work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of users with their most recent logon across all domain controllers store the usernames in a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) that you update whenever you find a user that isn't in the hashtable yet or has a more recent logon timestamp:

```psh
$users = @{}

Get-ADDomainController | % {
  Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -Server $_.Name -Property lastLogon | % {
    $user = $_.SamAccountName
    $time = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogon)

    if (-not $users.Contains($user) -or $users[$user] -lt $time) {
      $users[$user] = $time
    }
  }
}
```

Afterwards the hashtable can be exported to a CSV like this:

```psh
$users.GetEnumerator() | % {
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property [ordered]@{
    SamAccountName = $_.Name
    LastLogon      = $_.Value
  }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\lastlogons.csv' -NoType
```

or, if you really need that boatload of other attributes, like this:

```psh
$attributes = 'Name', 'SamAccountName', 'Description', 'EmployeeID',
              'EmployeeNumber', 'EmailAddress', 'Manager', 'Title',
              'Department', 'Organization', 'Enabled'

Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -Property $attributes |
  select $attributes, @{n='LastLogon';e={$users[$_.SamAccountName]}} |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\lastlogons.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not quite understand what to do, but do I save each of these 2 as their own .ps1 files and run them back to back to get it to work?

Comment: The first and one of the other two snippets go in one script.

Answer (score 0):

We use the following Function to determine the lastlogon

```psh
function Measure-LoggedOn {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,Position=0)]
    $DistinguishedName,
    [string[]]$DomainControllers
)
$RealLastLogon = $null 
$LastusedDC = $null 
foreach ($DomainController in $DomainControllers) {
    try{
        $Obj = $null
        $Obj = Get-ADObject -Identity $DistinguishedName -Properties LastLogon -Server $DomainController
        Write-Verbose "[$($Obj.Name)] Last logon on $DomainController : $([DateTime]::FromFileTime($Obj.LastLogon))"
        if ($RealLastLogon -le [DateTime]::FromFileTime($Obj.LastLogon)) { 
            $RealLastLogon = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($Obj.LastLogon)
            $LastusedDC =  $DomainController
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "Error checking LastLogon attribute for $DistinguishedName on Domain Controller $DomainController"
    }
}
return $RealLastLogon
}
```

This way, you could use the following code to export the properties to a CSV:

```psh
# Outside the loop, determine al DCs
$ADInfo = Get-ADDomain
[string[]]$DCs = $ADInfo.ReplicaDirectoryServers

Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -Properties Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,Manager,Title,Department,Organization,Enabled -SearchBase "DC=webcoindustries,DC=com" | ` 
? {$_.EmployeeID -notlike "EXCLUDE" } | `
Select Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,@{N='Last Logon'; E={(Measure-LoggedOn -DistinguishedName $_.DistinguishedName -DomainControllers $DCs)}},Manager,Title,Department,Organization,Enabled | `
Export-Csv "C:\scripts\AD_Export_Test\AD_Export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I added both of those scripts into one script and this is the error I am getting: <http://i.imgur.com/L7urtp5.png> Any thoughts?

Comment: Changed it a bit (missed "E={") and also it looks like the property "Organization"  is not copied correctly to your editor. Can you change it manually?

Comment: I got it to run for a second, but now it is saying invalid enumeration context.

Comment: I just copied above to PowerShell ISE and noticed that the property "Organization" and also "Last Logon" gave strange output. Instead of copying above I just typed it and it worked flawlessley (of course I removed the `-SearchBase "DC=webcoindustries,DC=com"`).